# Is there bad effects by frequently reinstalling Windows?

Tags: windows

My friend have a laptop that often got reinstalled windows. Usually, when his laptop runs slowly, he will try to refresh the laptop by reinstalling the Windows. But, in a online computer forum, i ever told that frequently reinstalling windows would be make the Harddisk got a problem, such as Bad Sector. Is the statement true? Is there bad effects by frequently reinstalling Windows?

Comment: No; The statement is 100% false and impossible to prove.  I have had a HDD that eventually failed and had bad sectors, and I not once in the lifetime of said HDD, reinstalled Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My friend have a laptop... 
>   Usually, when his laptop runs slowly, he will try to refresh the laptop
>   by reinstalling the Windows.

That usually works. A better way is to find out **why** the computer runs slow and to prevent that.

> On an online computer forum, i ever told that frequently reinstalling
>   windows would be make the Harddisk got a problem, such as Bad Sector.
>   Is the statement true?

Nope. It is nonsense.

Frequent writing to a sector might wear that sector out, but even on spinning disks that is a slow process. A few hundred windows reinstallation to the same place on the disk will not be enough to cause a problem. A few tens of thousands might, but I doubt that anyway will reinstall windows that often before buying new hardware.

> Is there bad effects by frequently reinstalling Windows?

You loose lots of time doing the reinstallation. If your friend thinks it is fun to reinstall, then let him. Otherwise:

1. Figure out what makes the old OS slow. (E.g. does (s)he has a small child without own account which constantly installs dozens of toolbars? Etc etc.
2. If you want to start with a clean OS then take an image of a clean installed OS and restore that. Instead of reinstalling the whole OS and spending hours downloading windows updates you could 'refresh' in minute to a state where it is clean and already has most updates.

Regardless of that, once more: No, the drive will not go bad because of reinstalling the OS.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe on your hard drive because its the same deleting and writing as if you install or uninstall a program. Other than that, it wont harm your computer, in fact it will be faster.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).